# accessing a DynamoDBStreams stream with Kinesis SDK

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-dynamodb-streams

It it possible to access streams defined by the DynamoDBStreams service with the Kinesis SDK?
For example, using C++, is it possible to get info on a stream added by, say

```
$ aws dynamodb update-table --stream-specification ...
```

with

```
Aws::Kinesis::KinesisClient::DescribeStream()
```

?
(This would mean "switching" the service Kinesis targets. AFAIK it is not possible since Kinesis and DynamoDBStreams services are disjunct, however, they have common conceptual points.)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible, yet they do share a [similar API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html):

> The DynamoDB Streams API provides the following actions for use by
>   application programs:
>
> - ListStreams—returns a list of stream descriptors for the current    account and endpoint. You can optionally request just the stream
>     descriptors for a particular table name.
> - DescribeStream—returns detailed information about a given stream. The output includes a list of shards associated with the stream,
>     including the shard IDs.
> - GetShardIterator—returns a shard iterator, which describes a location within a shard. You can request that the iterator provide
>     access to the oldest point, the newest point, or a particular point in
>     the stream.
> - GetRecords—returns the stream records from within a given shard. You must provide the shard iterator returned from a GetShardIterator
>     request.